# Save button for SQL Server in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a Save button for SQL Server in vb.net. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. I get this error:

> This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

as soon as I click on the button.

My code Looks like this.

```
Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.AnimalDetailsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Animal_RecordsDataSet)
End Sub
```

It worked fine but not anymore.

The error comes up at:

```
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Animal_RecordsDataSet)
```

I am new to working with databases in software. Can anybody please let me know where I went wrong or what I should do different?

Comment: Does "As soon as I click on the button" mean that `Me.Validate()` doesn't even execute?

Comment: Your error message mentions a transaction but your code does not.  Are you creating a transaction yourself?

Comment: @Brad, he says that the exception is thrown on the `UpdateAll` call so `Validate` and `EndEdit` must be executing successfully.  I think that this is a case of a developer talking to other developer's from a user's perspective.

Comment: I had a trigger on the database that insert values from table A column 1,2 to table B column 1,2. When I disabled the trigger in the data base the save button worked again. So it means something is wrong with the trigger. I will do some more research on triggers in sql server. Thanks to every one.